# How to add visual annotations to an image using python in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

The overall objective is to view medical images from some server, add visual annotations to the image (i.e., highlighting/circling a tumor in red), then upload those images back to the server with the annotation as some sort of metadata.

The viewing/uploading/storing metadata is essentially complete, but I have yet to find any packages that allow me to draw on the images within jupyter notebooks. This could either manipulate the pixels or essentially create a new image on top of the displayed image.

I'm currently displaying the image data using matplotlib.

I've seen some use of javascript to track mouse movement and keystrokes, but can't figure out how to use that to my advantage. I can use any package, so long as it works within jupyter.

Comment: I don't think Jupyter is the right tool for the job, it seems you want to develop a web application.

Comment: @Edu While I do agree with you, unfortunately this is my current limitation with work :/

Comment: To clarify your question, are you saying that you'd like to be able to first display the raw image and then *by tracking mouse movement and clicks* draw  circles and arrows on that image- and do it all within the context of a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @michael_j_ward, Correct. Obviously, displaying the image is simple enough. Tracking mouse movement and clicks is possible within the context. Just not sure how to apply it to drawing, if its possible.

Comment: @sutartmelson, got it. Perhaps this could be useful: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/cursor_demo.html

And this stackoverflow discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136938/matplotlib-interactive-graphing-manually-drawing-lines-on-a-graph

I have never done anything like this myself though. If you find a solution please share it.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar in 2024. For Googlers landing here, I found these but none looks maintained:
https://github.com/gereleth/jupyter-bbox-widget
https://github.com/janfreyberg/ipyannotations
https://github.com/gereleth/jupyter-bbox-widget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions from @michael_j_ward, I found a solution. I looked through those discussions and tutorials as well as read the documentation for the matplotlib axes. This is what I came up with/altered

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import numpy as np
import dicom


class Annotator(object):
    def __init__(self, axes):
        self.axes = axes

        self.xdata = []
        self.ydata = []

    def mouse_move(self, event):
        if not event.inaxes:
            return

        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata

        self.xdata.append(x)
        self.ydata.append(y)
        line = Line2D(self.xdata,self.ydata)
        line.set_color('r')
        self.axes.add_line(line)

        plt.draw()

    def mouse_release(self, event):
        # Erase x and y data for new line
        self.xdata = []
        self.ydata = []

path = '../sample.dcm'

data = dicom.read_file(path)

img = data.pixel_array

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.imshow(img[0])
plt.axis("off")
plt.gray()
annotator = Annotator(axes)
plt.connect('motion_notify_event', cursor.mouse_move)
plt.connect('button_release_event', cursor.mouse_release)

axes.plot()

plt.show()
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohezn.jpg)

It allows me to open images and draw on them to highlight or annotate significant portions of the image.

Comment: Where is `cursor` from? I'm getting NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined

Comment: @MrMartin I think it should be `annotator`.

Comment: Did this work in a Jupyter notebook? I couldn't get it to draw anything on the image.

Answer (score -2):

Inside Jupyter notebook you can use:

```
%matplotlib inline
```